# Shiny ModalDialog with InsertUI

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a button which calls a modal dialog where a UI should be inserted. I'm using `insertUI` because I want to add UI elements dynamically. The problem is, whenever I press the action button, the app crashes with the following error message:

```
Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
  [No stack trace available]
```

If I set `immediate = T` in the `insertUI()` then there is no error, but also no UI inserted. Can someone explain what's going on here? Here's a reprex.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "addConstraints")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$add, {

    showModal(modalDialog(
      selectizeInput(session$ns("constraintType"), label = "Select constraint type", choices = c("Comparison", "Numeric", "Interval")),
      tags$div(id = session$ns("constraintPlaceholder")),
      insertUI(
        selector = paste0("#", session$ns("constraintPlaceholder")),
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = HTML("test")
      ),
      title = "Set Constraints",
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton(session$ns("confirmConstraint"), "Add")
      )
    ))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertUI` needs to be called outside `modalDialog`. What inside `modalDialog` is UI components, they should be shinyTags, or HTML elements. `insertUI` is a server call, it can't be added to `modalDialog`

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "addConstraints")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$add, {

    showModal(modalDialog(
      selectizeInput(session$ns("constraintType"), label = "Select constraint type", choices = c("Comparison", "Numeric", "Interval")),
      tags$div(id = session$ns("constraintPlaceholder")),
      title = "Set Constraints",
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton(session$ns("confirmConstraint"), "Add")
      )
    ))
    insertUI(
          selector = paste0("#", session$ns("constraintPlaceholder")),
          where = "afterEnd",
          ui = HTML("test")
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I have a similar question, where I need to insertui within the module, and this seems like a good idea, but the Add button inside the module here doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: The Add button here has an ID of  `confirmConstraint`. It actual button with ID `add` is outside with text `addConstraints`.  So yes, the Add button inside the modal does not do anything.